# Hierarchical Category sorting with subCategory's ID

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have problem about the hierarchical category sort in mssql.I have sql code that lists category with their level in the following code segment.

`WITH TempCtgry (CtgryID, CtgryName, ParentCtgryId, Lvl)AS (SELECT CategoryID,CategoryName ,ParentCatID, 0 as Level FROM Category  r WHERE r.ParentCatID IS NULL UNION ALL SELECT  r1.CategoryID, r1.CategoryName, r1.ParentCatID, TempCtgry.Lvl+1 FROM Category  r1 INNER JOIN TempCtgry on r1.ParentCatID= TempCtgry.CtgryID) SELECT * FROM TempCtgry`

But I want to show sub category's parents.For Example: Television >> Smart >> Lcd Tv

How can I do that?

Thanks and King Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build it up as you go, just like counting levels:

```
WITH TempCtgry ( CtgryID, CtgryName, ParentCtgryId, Lvl ) AS (
  SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, ParentCatID, 0 as Level,
    Convert( VarChar(1024), CategoryName ) as Path
    FROM Category r
    WHERE r.ParentCatID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT r1.CategoryID, r1.CategoryName, r1.ParentCatID, TempCtgry.Lvl + 1,
    Convert( VarChar(1024), Path + ' >> ' + r1.CategoryName ) as Path
    FROM Category r1 INNER JOIN
      TempCtgry on r1.ParentCatID = TempCtgry.CtgryID
  )
  SELECT *
    FROM TempCtgry
```

To display the path as links on a web page, you'll want to have both the category names for display and the corresponding ids for use in the links.  A simple separator that allows you to use a string split function, e.g. [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx), simplifies the display code:

```
WITH TempCtgry ( CtgryID, CtgryName, ParentCtgryId, Lvl ) AS (
  SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName, ParentCatID, 0 as Level,
    Convert( VarChar(1024), CategoryName ) as Path,
    Convert( VarChar(1024), CategoryID ) as PathIds
    FROM Category r
    WHERE r.ParentCatID IS NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT r1.CategoryID, r1.CategoryName, r1.ParentCatID, TempCtgry.Lvl + 1,
    Convert( VarChar(1024), Path + '|' + r1.CategoryName ) as Path,
    Convert( VarChar(1024), PathIds + '|' + Convert( VarChar(9), CategoryId ) ) as PathIds
    FROM Category r1 INNER JOIN
      TempCtgry on r1.ParentCatID = TempCtgry.CtgryID
  )
  SELECT *
    FROM TempCtgry
```

Note: This assumes that a vertical bar ("|") cannot occur in a category name.

The ASP.NET code will need to split both path strings and walk down them together creating links as it goes.  A convenient display separator is "»" (U+00BB: Right-Pointing Double Angle Quotation Mark).

It is possible to add all of the code to generate the required HTML into the query, but that isn't where it belongs.

Comment: How can i enter link in asp.net.It's working good but When I want to show that in asp.net page it gives me string and how can I give link to each cateogry in the path column? Thanks

Comment: @KaanKılıç - Updated answer to show how to handle both the category names and ids for building links.

Comment: Thank you sir.King regards to good answer.It's worked for me.